# Validação Unique PUT and POST UNIQUE em REQUEST Laravel

Tags: crud, restrição-único, laravel-8

Estou com Um problema na hora de validar o campo unique.
Meu problema antes era q se fosse atualizar o valor ele não editava, porque acusava q o valor era unique, resolvi ele, porém agora ele não valida o campo unique, mas atualiza kkk

Esse é meu Request - Já tentei esses 3 métodos e eles só deixam atualizar o campo! Não valida se o valor é único antes de enviar pro banco!

```
public function rules()
{
    return[/*'nome'=>'bail|required|min:3|max:250|',Rule::unique('service')->ignore($this->service),*/

        'nome'=> 'bail|required|min:3|max:250|unique:service,nome,'.$this->id.',id',

        /*'nome' => 'bail|required|min:3|max:250',Rule::unique('service','nome')->ignore($this->service),*/
        'observacao'=> 'required'
    ];
}
```

Agora meu Controller

```
public function create()
{
    $action = route('admin.service.store');
    return view('admin.cadastro.service',compact('action'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function store(ServiceRequest $request)
{
    Service::create($request->all());
    return  redirect()->route('admin.gerencial.index')->with('success_message', 'Cadastrado com Sucesso');
}
```

Já tentei de várias formas e não consigo fazer! Preciso de ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema! Como imaginei qdo estava rodando a validação em rules no campo UNIQUE ele só faz uma tarefa ou ignora ou atribui! Nesse caso ele estava só ignorando o ID quando estava atualizando e não validava o unique no create.

```
Rule::unique('service')->ignore($this->service)
```

Agora pra corrigir tive que fazer essa validação dentro de RULES no Request

```
$regras=[
        'campos do banco'          => 'bail|required|min:3|max:150',
        'endereco'      => 'required|min:3|max:200',
        'cities_id'     => 'required',
        'states_id'     => 'required'
    ];

    if ($this->method() === "POST"){
        $regras['coluna UNIQUE']= [
            'required',Rule::unique('client')
        ];
    }
    else{
        $regras['coluna UNIQUE']= [
        'required',Rule::unique('table')->ignore($this->route)
    ];
}
    return $regras;
```